# How to make a console-based menu out of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, menu, console

I am trying to make a library for future works as part of an assignment, and I have most of it done, however I can't figure out how to make a console-based menu out of an array the user inputs. Just to clarify, I'm not asking for the answer because I have barely started, but what I'd like is a good starting place to go on, like a command or something I can use. I will pos`/**
     * Generates a console-based menu using the Strings in options as the menu
     * items. Reserves the number 0 for the "quit" option when withQuit is true.
     * 
     * @param options
     *            - Strings representing the menu options
     * @param withQuit
     *            - adds option 0 for "quit" when true
     * @return the int of the selection made by the user
     */

```
    public static int promptForMenuSelection(String[] options, boolean withQuit) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String.
}`
```

Sorry If the requirements above the code are hard to read. Please help, this is one of the last two tasks in the assignment, and I'm ready to have it done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you check what the user inputs, you can match that with the index of the array. For example:

```
// Scanner for user input:
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

// Gets the index (Surround with try/catch to prevent errors)
int userRequest = Integer.ParseInt(scanner.nextLine());

if(withQuit && userRequest == 0)
     return // Whatever value you want to return here on quit;

if(userRequest - 1 > options.length)
     return // Whatever value you want to return when the request is out of range; 

for(int i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
     if(options[i] == userRequest - 1)
          return i; // Returns the option index
```

Since you're trying to return an integer, I'm assuming you won't care about the value in the array. But if you do, just set the return statement to be:

```
return options[i];
```

and have the return set to String instead of int in the function header.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I won't lie, I don't entirely understand all this, but since I'm a visual learner I might get it as I do it. Thanks again.